# Excel VBA - How do copy dynamic background color of excel cell to email body using macro?

Tags: vba, email, excel, dynamic

This is an Excel file, here red color is static background and green color is dynamic background and it will change based on dynamic value as mentioned below.
![enter image description here][1]

I have used below code to copy the selected range of Excel sheet and paste it in email body.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
'Only the visible cells in the selection
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'You can also use a fixed range if you want
'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Save   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

After run the above code  all values are copied in Email except dynamic background color. Please help me out.
![enter image description here][2]

Comment: links of your images are removed !! ;).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Range in Middle of Email Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420752/range-in-middle-of-the-email-body/29421995#29421995). My code there also uses Ron de Bruin's `RangeToHTML` method and copies/preserves all cell formats into the email body.