# How to send worksheet in email body?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way I can attach as well as send a worksheet as an email body.

The below VBA code sends the worksheet as an attachment.

How can I send a worksheet in the body of email?

```vb
Sub Email()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Worksheet").Copy
    
    
    Set wbTemp = ActiveWorkbook
    
    
    wbTemp.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "TestWb", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    
    strFilename = wbTemp.FullName
    
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "test@testdomain.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test Email"
        .Body = ""
        .Attachments.Add strFilename
        .display
    End With
    
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    wbTemp.Close
    
    Kill strFilename
    
End Sub
```

Comment: [Here's a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18683610/3657636) that answers what you are looking for. Also, [this website by Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) covers the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

     Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:g15")

     Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

     With Sendrng
    .Parent.Select
    Set rng = ActiveCell
     .Select
      ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope
            With .Item
                .To = "recipient"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "My subject"
                .Send
            End With

        End With
              rng.Select
    End With

        AWorksheet.Select

Sheet1.Activate
Range("c2:c3").ClearContents
Range("e2:e3").ClearContents
Range("c5") = ""
Range("B8:b10").ClearContents
Range("c8:c10").ClearContents
Range("d8:d10").ClearContents
Range("e8:e10").ClearContents
Range("f8:f10").ClearContents
Range("g8:g10").ClearContents
Range("b13") = ""



 StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

you should add your code that also copies it to this. Forgive all the crap you dont need here, I just copy and pasted one I have been using