# Display a Range part of the email body vba

Tags: vba, excel, email, range

I would like to add a range from my sheet to the body of an email which is generated but vba. I keep getting errors and any help would be appreciated

```
myRange = Range("A12:A12.End(xlDown)").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'This will extract the info for the worksheet
'This extracts the subject title from the worksheet

EmailSubject = "STOCKS " & Type1 & " - " & Left(Trade, 6) & " [" & _ 
               Range("A12").Value & "/" & Range("A12").End(xlDown).Value _
               & "]: % at %"

Body = "<b>" & Range("A8").Value & "</b><br/>" & Range("A9").Value & "<br/>" _ 
       & Range("A10").Value & "<br/><br/>" _
       & myRange
```

Comment: The code snippet as is doesn't even compile, specifically, the `EmailSubject...` part. You need a "_" at the end of the line.

Comment: its all in one line, its just the editor here that cut it

Comment: Sounds strange, but you really should edit your post then. Generally, posting code that doesn't even compile is a big no no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in the way you are declaring the range.

- Range is an object and it has to be `Set`
- `End(xlDown)` cannot be passed as a String
- Try to define the start and the end cell of the range and then the range is going to be defined correctly:

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim firstCell   As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range

    Set firstCell = Range("A12")
    Set lastCell = firstCell.End(xlDown)
    Set myRange = Range(firstCell, lastCell).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

End Sub
```

Once you manage to have the correct range, it would be easier - [Paste specific excel range in outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663127/paste-specific-excel-range-in-outlook)

Comment: @theudster - simply take the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683610/5448626) and declare your range as in my answer. It should work.