# Trying to Copy Excel Table into On-click Email Macro

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using an on-click macro to create and autofill an email in Outlook. Forgive me, as I haven't coded in VBA as much. Below is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hello " & Range("E6").Value & "and " & Range("E7").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "boo"
                


        On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = Range("E6")
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("E2")
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

My table is form d2-e29. Right now, "boo" is my placeholder for where the table should go. How can I get my table to be in the Mail Body?

Comment: https://youtu.be/f8s-jY9y220&t=4440

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paste Excel range in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663127/paste-excel-range-in-outlook)

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is usually inappropriate. Note it is used in `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)` but removed elsewhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753201/vba-how-long-does-on-error-resume-next-work/31753321#31753321