# How to add a Signature on Excel

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have an Excel spreadsheet Auditing Vendor documentation  with expiry dates.
I have created an VBA macro which when I choose **(Ctrl + M)** will send an email requesting updates for specific documents based on the expiry dates.

Everything is beautiful and works like a charm.

My question is how do I include an Outlook Signature at the end of the email?
I would like it to pick up based on whoever has the spreadsheet open so that if Charlie Brown wants to trigger an email it would include Charlie Brown's Signature at the end.

It already auto-fills Charlie Brown as the Sender so I should be able to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The downvoter might have been more charitable had you included information about the code rather than the button pressing. This could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-outlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Example

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddSignature()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    With olMail
        .Display olMail.HTMLbody '<- adding default signature
    End With

    With olMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .HTMLbody = "Hello." & "<br>" & .HTMLbody '<- adding default signature
        .Display
'        .Send
    End With

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

[also see Insert Signature in mail](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm) From ***Ron de Bruin***

Answer (score 0):

If you use excel to grab the new mail item signature you will get a flag for suspicious activity that the user could acknowledge

```
Dim OApp, OMail As Object
Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim sig As String
sig = OMail.HTMLbody
```

If you know the name of the signature you can go browse for it

```
Dir (CStr(Environ$("userprofile")) & "\appdata\roaming\microsoft\signatures\")
```