# Delete from new mail a signature copied from old mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I select any mail to open a new mail item with a mailbody made up if the Subject, MailBody and FromSenderAddress of selected mail.

I get the signature content of the selected mail in my new mail body.

How do I eliminate the Signature content (Thanks..Regards...xxxxx.etc;) so it is not in my new mailbody.

```
Public Sub CreateNewMessage()

Dim objMsg As MailItem
Dim Selection As Selection
Dim obj As Object

Set Selection = ActiveExplorer.Selection

For Each obj In Selection

    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objMsg
      .To = ""
      .CC = ""
      .BCC = ""
      .Subject = ""
      .Body = "<Subject> " & obj.Subject & _ 
           " </Subject>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "<Mail> " & obj.Body & " </Mail>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "<Sender> " & obj.SenderEmailAddress & " </Sender>"
      .Sensitivity = olConfidential
      .Display
    End With

    Set objMsg = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i don't think the signature is saved in a seperate part of the email, so detecting it would only be possible by text search. But maybe there is a hack with "ObjMail.HTMLBody = ObjMail.Body". Look at this post , there the Problem was the opposite -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-Outlook

If somebody gives you a clean way to detect the Body, i would recommend to NOT use my comment ;)

Comment: ya, the signature is included in the mail body of the selected mail. So, how   to do text search of such content in the `.Body` of the `objMsg`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a keyword in the signature, which is always the same like "best regards" you can use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteAfterText()

' Deletes all text after endStr.

Dim currMail As mailitem
Dim msgStr As String

Dim endStr As String
Dim endStrStart As Long
Dim endStrLen As Long

Set currMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
endStr = "Best Regards"
endStrLen = Len(endStr)

msgStr = currMail.HTMLBody
endStrStart = InStr(msgStr, endStr)

If endStrStart > 0 Then
    currMail.HTMLBody = Left(msgStr, endStrStart + endStrLen)
End If

End Sub
```

if you don't have a keyword, or different ones, it can be hard to find the signature

Comment: i have seen this code before, but where do i call this code in `.Body` of my code.

Comment: just Change currMail to objMsg

Comment: Thats ok... But where do i call this DeleteAfterText() method in my `.Body` code.

Comment: ah no of course you Need your object obj, you should call the function before the with

Comment: I tried running the macro by adding the code you provided, but it is displaying " Run-time error `91`: object variable or with block variable not set" and that too the selected mail