# vba outlook embed image url

Tags: vba, outlook, add-in

I am trying to insert a hosted image to the body of my message. Here is what i have done so far:

```
Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    If Not (mailItem Is Nothing) Then
        If mailItem.EntryID Is Nothing Then
            mailItem.Subject = "Test"
            mailItem.Body = mailItem.Body + "<html><img src='http://example.com/pixel.php?to=" + mailItem.To + "></html>"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The above inserts doesnt actually embed the image, it just adds the line:

```
<html><img src='http://example.com/pixel.php?to=" + mailItem.To + "></html>
```

To my my email body.

How can i get it embedded?

Comment: mailItem.Body is for plain text you need to use  mailItem.HTMLBody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment you are using MailItem.Body which is for plain text.  Switch to HTMLBody

```
Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    If Not (mailItem Is Nothing) Then
        If mailItem.EntryID Is Nothing Then
            mailItem.Subject = "Test"
            mailItem.HTMLBody = mailItem.HTMLBody + "<html><img src='http://example.com/pixel.php?to=" + mailItem.To + "></html>"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Sorceri. This seems to overwrite the signature that is automatically applied to new emails?

Comment: See here on how to keep the signature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-outlook