# How do I find the file name of the user's Outlook default signature?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've written an Excel add-in to send emails using Outlook. I've come up with a way to add the user's signature. The fly in the ointment though is that they change the names of their signatures.

How can I get the user's default signature from Outlook?

```vb
    Dim salutation As String, ourRef As String, amount As String, customerName As String, yourRef As String
    Dim totalAmount As Double

    ' salutation
    salutation = IIf(Time < 0.5, "Good morning", "Good afternoon")

    ' opening text
    totalAmount = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(Table, 1)
        totalAmount = totalAmount + Table(i, 3)
    Next i

    body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>"
    body = body & "<div style=""font-family:'Segoe UI', Calibri, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 14px; max-width: 768px;"">"
    If bulk = True Then
        body = body & salutation & "<br /><br />We have sent you a bulk payment totaling " _
        & Format(totalAmount, "£##,##0.00") & ", to be credited to the following accounts: <br /><br />"
    Else
        body = body & salutation & "<br /><br />We have sent you the following payments: <br /><br />"
    End If

    ' table header
    body = body & "<style type='text/css'>.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;" _
        & "border-width: 1px;border-color: #9dcc7a;border-collapse: collapse;}.tftable th {font-size:12px;" _
        & "background-color:#A99D36;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: " _
        & "#9dcc7a;text-align:left;}.tftable tr {background-color:#F0EDCF;}.tftable td {font-size:12px;" _
        & "border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;}"
    body = body & "</style><table class='tftable' border='1'><tr><th>Our ref</th><th>Amount</th>" _
        & "<th>Client name</th><th>Your ref</th></tr>"

    ' table body
    For i = LBound(Table, 1) To UBound(Table, 1)

        ourRef = Table(i, 1)
        amount = Table(i, 3)
        customerName = Table(i, 2)
        yourRef = Table(i, 4)

        body = body & "<tr>"
        body = body & "<td>" & ourRef & "</td>"
        body = body & "<td>" & Format(amount, "£##,##0.00") & "</td>"
        body = body & "<td>" & customerName & "</td>"
        body = body & "<td>" & yourRef & "</td>"
        body = body & "</tr>"

    Next i

    body = body & "</tbody></table>"

    ' signature
    enviro = CStr(Environ("appdata"))
    Debug.Print enviro
    Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strSigFilePath = enviro & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    Debug.Print strSigFilePath
    Set objSignatureFile = objfso.opentextfile(strSigFilePath & "Standard.htm")
    strbuffer = objSignatureFile.ReadAll
    body = body & "<br/><br/>" & strbuffer
    objSignatureFile.Close

End Function
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your relevant code parts or a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of having the code create the signature, did you try just adding `.Display` before the `.Send` to mail object when it is created? That will add the users signature to the email before sending.

Comment: No doesn't work because the signature is not just text need to pull an image through as well.

Comment: @Stevie D Outlook Object Model does not expose signatures at all.

On a general note, the name of the signature is stored in the account profile data accessible through the `IOlkAccountManager Extended` `MAPI interface`. Since that interface is Extended MAPI, it can only be accessed using C++ or Delphi. You can see the interface and its data in OutlookSpy if you click the  `IOlkAccountManager` button. If using Redemption is an option. `Redemption` also exposes `RDOSignature`. This is just to share knowledge, my scope is restricted to `Excel VBA ` only.

Comment: Thanks skkakkar looks like this is going to be a bit tricky then.

Comment: a link to the answer quoted by @skkakkar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-outlook/32391722#32391722

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko I just keep extracts of important points in my notes of reputed experts like you, hence was not able to provide your link. Thanks for pointing to the link. I never intended to answer the question, it were in comments only and I also restricted and clarified my scope. I hope you  will pardon me for any wrong doing inadvertently.

Comment: @skkakka - no problem at all: I just wanted the OP to see the whole discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Stevie, if I may so bold to Answer this...

1. The signature file is located - `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures`
2. Their personal files for images are - `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\[singatureName]_files` Ex: "Business_files"
3. The images appear to pull in ***image00#.jpg*** indexing
4. You can try using ***HTMLBody*** VS just ***body***
5. You can use `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` to get the users default email account, thus getting that accounts' Signature

Perhaps when you use the `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder`, then can look at signature name, then can do the `[name]_files` to get any images they may have in there. Please note that if you use ***HTMLBody***, as it's an issue with my company, the user will have a block from the *Programmatic Access* Trust Center settings in Outlook. THis prompts the user with an Allow/Deny box, in which they can select to Allow for up to 10 minutes... just FYI.

Hope some of this helps.
Danny,
[ExcelVBADude](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5Z93LJulIuAICkZMSmcbGA?view_as=subscriber)

Answer (score 0):

You can read "New Signature" and "Reply-Forward Signature" binary values from the registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles[profileName]\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676[accountNO]\