# Excel Range to Outlook Body with VBA - Need help to add default signature

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Currently I am using this VBA Code to copy the selected excel range to a new email in outlook:

```
Sub SendSelectedCells_inOutlookEmail()
Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strTempHTMLFile As String
Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objTextStream As Object
Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem

'Copy the selection
Set objSelection = Selection
Selection.Copy

'Paste the copied selected ranges into a temp worksheet
Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Keep the values, column widths and formats in pasting
With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

'Save the temp worksheet as a HTML file
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)

'Create a new email
Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Read the HTML file data and insert into the email body
Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)
objNewEmail.HTMLBody = objTextStream.ReadAll
objNewEmail.Display
'You can specify the new email recipients, subjects here using the following lines:
'objNewEmail.To = "johnsmith@datanumen.com"
'objNewEmail.Subject = "DataNumen Products"
'objNewEmail.Send --> directly send out this email

objTextStream.Close
objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
End Sub
```

It works but it doesn't add my default signature to the new email,
Can anybody help me out with this?

Thanks all for your help.

Edit:
This is the Macro with the Default Signature

```
Sub SendSelectedCells_inOutlookEmail()
Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strTempHTMLFile As String
Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objTextStream As Object
Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strSig As String

'Copy the selection
Set objSelection = Selection
Selection.Copy

'Paste the copied selected ranges into a temp worksheet
Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Keep the values, column widths and formats in pasting
With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

'Save the temp worksheet as a HTML file
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)

'Create a new email
Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Read the HTML file data and insert into the email body
Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)
objNewEmail.Display
strSig = objNewEmail.HTMLBody
objNewEmail.HTMLBody = objTextStream.ReadAll & strSig

'You can specify the new email recipients, subjects here using the following lines:
'objNewEmail.To = "johnsmith@datanumen.com"
'objNewEmail.Subject = "DataNumen Products"
'objNewEmail.Send --> directly send out this email

objTextStream.Close
objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
```

End Sub

Thank you Dmitry for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add default signature in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-outlook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook adds the signature if you call `MailItem.Display` and you have not modified `Body` or `HTMLBody` properties prior to calling Display.

Call `Display` first, read the `HTNMLBody` property (it will contain the signature), then merge it with your data.

Comment: Thanks!! I've managed to figure it out :)