# Add signature to mass email and change the from account

Tags: vba, outlook

I can't get the signature onto the email and change the from account.

With this code the signature is inserted but it doesn't keep the formatting.

I tried another one that copied it from a Word document but it never worked.

```vb
Sub Send_Mails()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim I As Integer
    
Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object
Dim OutAccount As Outlook.Account
    
Set OA = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    
Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Application.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
    
Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
    
With msg
    .Display
End With
Signature = msg.Body
    
For I = 2 To last_row
    
    'msg.Display
    
    msg.To = sh.Range("A" & I).Value
    msg.cc = sh.Range("B" & I).Value
    msg.Subject = sh.Range("C" & I).Value
    msg.Body = sh.Range("D" & I).Value & Signature
         
    If sh.Range("E" & I).Value <> "" Then
        msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("E" & I).Value
    End If
    
    'msg.send
    
    sh.Range("F" & I).Value = "Sent"
    
Next I
    
MsgBox "All the mails have been sent successfully"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: So you are trying to send out mass emails and have it look like it's coming from someone besides you? Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Because we have a general account ex. Info@company.com and we send out all the official communications from that account :)

Comment: Take a look at [Send email from another address using VBA](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/send-email-address-vba) and [Insert Outlook Signature in mail](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm).

Comment: Use `.HTMLBody` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12990825/1571407.

Comment: Focus on one question per post.

Comment: @ElioFernandes thank you so much! the first part worked perfectly sendonbehalfof :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @community should I edit it even though I got the answers to both questions ? I was able to change the from account using the send on behalf of and add the signature using the HTML.body property

Answer (score 0):

The signature doesn't preserve the original formatting because a plain-text property was used in the code.

```
Signature = msg.Body
```

Instead, you need to use the `HTMLBody` property which returns an HTML markup with all formatting set up. Also you may consider using the Word object model (see the `WordEditor` property of the Inspector class).

To set up the From account correctly to the one which is set up in an Outlook profile you can use the [SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. For example:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

Also if you have configured sufficient privileges on the Exchange server side you may consider using the [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property which returns a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message.