# How to get signature, without showing screen, while sending emails through VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a spreadsheet with a list of email addresses (for this example imagine the email addresses are in Cell A1 to Cell A100).

I need to send a different email to each email address in this range. To keep the signature I must display the email and this makes the macro take a lot of time to run.

I have seen questions that use `.GetInspector`. The issue I have with this is once it sends the first email and sets it to nothing `.GetInspector` interferes with opening the mail item for the second email.

Is there any way to work around `.Display` with the code I have?

```vb
Sub Sendemails()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim signature As Variant
Dim rngemailaddress, Emailaddress As Range
Dim numberofrows As Long

numberofrows = Sheet1.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Set rngemailaddress = Range("A1:A" & numberofrows)
For Each Emailaddress In rngemailaddress.Cells
    Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With objMail
    
        '.Display is so i can save the signature
        .Display
        signature = .Htmlbody
        'instead of the line above i also tried "Signature = .GetInspector"
        
        .to = Emailaddress.Value
        .Subject = "Test email to not Display"
        .Htmlbody = "Input variable information here" & "<br><br>" & signature
        .Close olsave
    End With
    
    Set objMail = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

incase anyone sees this and needs an answer i have figured it out

```
Sub Sendemails()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim signature As Variant
Dim rngemailaddress, Emailaddress As Range
Dim numberofrows As Long


numberofrows = Sheet1.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Set rngemailaddress = Range("A1:A" & numberofrows)
For Each Emailaddress In rngemailaddress.Cells
Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMail

    '.Display is so i can save the signature
    signature = .Getinspector
    signature = .Htmlbody
    'instead of the line above i also tried "Signature = .GetInspector"
    
    .to = Emailaddress.Value
    .Subject = "Test email to not Display"
    .Htmlbody = "Input variable information here" & "<br><br>" & signature
    .Close olsave
End With

Set objMail = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This serendipitous "rediscovery" of the `.GetInspector` trick explained. [How to add default signature in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719341/1571407).

Answer (score 0):

To get the signature added to the mail item you need to call the `GetInspector` method before getting the `HTMLBody` property value.

```
With objMail

    .Getinspector
    signature = .Htmlbody
```