# Choose the signature to be inserted in an e-mail created via a button in VBA code from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, button, outlook

In my Excel spreadsheet, I have a VBA code button that allows me to generate an email with various pivot tables present in the same Excel file.

This is an email I can send myself, but I have a backup colleague who can also open the Excel file and send the email.

So, I would like to customize the signature insertion.

I would like that when I click on my email creation button in Excel, it opens a dialog box and asks me which signature I want to use.
This way, when I use it, I can choose my signature, and when a colleague uses it, they can choose their own.

I hope I am clear enough (not a native English speaker), and I thank you in advance for your assistance.

Have a great day!

Comment: Please [post your existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (as text)... it is much easier to help that way

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How are you getting setting the signature ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add default signature in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-outlook)