# All images in Outlook VBA Template do not show

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have the following macro - when it runs, no images display, instead showing the cross and the link is broken message. This happens with all images, embedded or not. I have tried changing all the trust settings but to no avail, as well as changing locations of all the images.

```
Sub Pitch()
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Dim objMatches As Object
    Dim strEmail As String
    Dim strMessageBody As String
    Dim objTemplate As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strTemplatePath As String
    Dim objSignature As Outlook.MailItem
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    
    If Not objMail Is Nothing Then
        Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With objRegExp
            .Pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)"
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
        End With
        
        Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(objMail.Body)
        
        If objMatches.Count > 0 Then
            strEmail = objMatches.Item(0).Value
            
            ' Extract the relevant portion from the original message body
            strMessageBody = Mid(objMail.Body, InStr(objMail.Body, "Message Details:"), InStr(objMail.Body, " Reply directly or go to your site's Inbox:") - InStr(objMail.Body, "Message Details:") - 1)
            
            ' Preserve line breaks
            strMessageBody = Replace(strMessageBody, vbCrLf, "<br>")
            
            Set objReply = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            
            ' Load the Outlook Template
            strTemplatePath = "C:\Users\fredd\Documents\.Pitch.oft"
            Set objTemplate = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strTemplatePath)
            
            ' Create a new mail item to get the default signature
            Set objSignature = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            
            With objReply
    .To = strEmail
    .Subject = "Your Yamp Camp Booking Enquiry"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML ' Ensure the email is in HTML format
    .HTMLBody = objTemplate.HTMLBody & strMessageBody & "<br><br>" & objSignature.HTMLBody
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@email.co.uk"
    .Display
End With
            
            ' Mark the specific email as read
            objMail.UnRead = False
        Else
            MsgBox "No email address found in the email body."
        End If
    End If
    
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objReply = Nothing
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
    Set objMatches = Nothing
    Set objTemplate = Nothing
    Set objSignature = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have tried changing locations of all image files as well as updating all trust / security settings in Outlook

Comment: See [How to add default signature in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-outlook). `Set objReply = CreateItemFromTemplate(strTemplatePath)` then `.Display` to get the signature before appending `.htmlbody = strMessageBody & "<br><br>" & .htmlbody`.