How do I add Outlooks default signature to my vba code?
I have the current vba code to autogenerate expiration emails for CPR compliance. I would like to add my default signature at the bottom of the email. How do I need to edit the following to do that?
Sub Send_Expired_CPR()
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olMailItm As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim Dest As Variant
Dim SDest As String

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem


' Create a new Outlook object
For iCounter = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

' Subject
strSubj = "Immediate Action Required: Expired CPR Certification for "
On Error GoTo dbg

' Create a new item (email) in Outlook
strBody = ""
useremail = Cells(iCounter, 4).Value
FirstName = Cells(iCounter, 5).Value
Expiration = Cells(iCounter, 9).Value
Login = Cells(iCounter, 3).Value
CertificationNumber = Cells(iCounter, 16).Value
CertificationVendor = Cells(iCounter, 15).Value


'Make the body of an email
strBody = "Dear " & FirstName & "," & vbCrLf
strBody = strBody & vbCrLf
strBody = strBody & "Your current CPR First Aid Certification from " & CertificationVendor & " (Certificaiton Number: " & CertificationNumber & ") is expired as of " & Expiration & "." & vbCrLf
strBody = strBody & vbCrLf
strBody = strBody & "Please work with your site leadership team to schedule a CPR First Aid Training class. Trainings must be scheduled two weeks in advance." & vbCrLf
strBody = strBody & vbCrLf
strBody = strBody & "Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!"
strBody = strBody & vbCrLf
objOutlookMsg.To = useremail
objOutlookMsg.Importance = olImportanceHigh
objOutlookMsg.Subject = strSubj & Login
objOutlookMsg.BodyFormat = 1

' 1 – text format of an email, 2 -  HTML format
objOutlookMsg.Body = strBody
objOutlookMsg.Display
Next iCounter

dbg:
'Display errors, if any
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description


Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

I have tried googling and searching a number of different previously asked questions.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728029/332059
