how to solve VBA run time error 2147023170: automation error the remote procedure call failed
I don't understand why if I run this code line by line with F8 the code works just fine, while if I run all together F5 I get

run time error 2147023170: Automation error. The remote procedure call failed.

I'm trying to send out bulk mails via Outlook. Especially runtime error pops up at the line msg.display.
Sub prepare_all()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Dim testo As Variant
    Dim destinatario As Variant
    Dim subject As Variant

    Set allEmails = [emails]
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        testo = sh.Range("F" & i).Value
        destinatario = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
        subject = sh.Range("G2").Value
        mail testo, destinatario, subject
    Next i

    MsgBox "Mail inviate con successo"
End Sub

Sub mail(testo As Variant, destinatario As Variant, subject As Variant)
    Dim Outlook_App As Object
    Dim msg As Object
    Dim sign As String
    Dim i As Integer
    'Dim testo As Text
    Set Outlook_App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    'Set msg = Outlook_App.CreateItem(0)

    Set msg = Outlook_App.CreateItem(0)

    msg.display

    sign = msg.HTMLBody

    With msg
        .To = destinatario
        .subject = subject
        .HTMLBody = testo & sign
        '.display
        .send
    End With

    Set msg = Nothing
    Set Outlook_App = Nothing
End Sub


Which language is this? Please [edit] to add a clear problem description, and also add a tag for the language (and probably remove the nonsensical [tag:mass]) and fix the formatting. Notice that you get a preview of what your post will look like below the editing pane. If your screen is wide enough, you also get a help button at the right of the editor’s menu strip, with a link to the full editing help

You need not .Display.  See .GetInspector here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719341/1571407.

The error is RPC_S_CALL_FAILED - this usually indicates that the remote COM server (Outlook) is processing an incoming or outgoing RPC call, and cannot process other calls.
Make sure you are not running this code when processing an Outlook event or, for example, tray icon event handler - I have seen this error in these two cases previously.
